# Learning Apache Ofbiz?

Tags: java, erp, ofbiz

i am a java developer, i have just started learning apache ofbiz,an open source enterprise automation software,i went through the tutorials on official apache ofbiz site,as ERP is a big thing in itself, this takes time to learn.

the question would sounds like asked by a novice, still, can anyone suggest what should be the proper flow (OR say better approach) for learning Ofbiz efficiently, like from where should i start,i mean sequence of topics i should start with or the prerequisities?

link to some example explaining basics will be great!!

Answer (score 2):

You learn it base on what you want to use it for.
Ofbiz is not to be used out of box. You need to customize it a bit to fit your needs. Customization doesn't mean programming, but making use of the modules you need. 
So the first question is what do you want to use it for. And move from there.

Good luck.

Comment: i have to utilize its hr module, and i am trying to understand its framework and tool,i have never worked on scripting language like beanshell,grovvy,jython etc. and specially have never worked on its default datasource derby, do i need to learn these topics before moving on further to this ofbiz??

Comment: I wouldn't recommend investing a lot of time trying to understand these details. Just focus on what you want, and try to understand the main components (service engine, entity engine ).

Comment: I actually change the default data source on my install to mysql, I'm only 24hrs in and I'd definitely say that having a goal will help the learning process. Does anyone have a tutorial on UI dev/modification? I'm looking but not found anything worthwhile yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous resources available that can help you learn Apache OFBiz.

Refer to tutorials from the official website that will give you an idea about basics:
[OFBiz Tutorial - A Beginners Development Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Tutorial+-+A+Beginners+Development+Guide)

Or refer the same on its official Youtube channel [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/ofbiz) or on Vimeo [here](https://vimeo.com/user2598348/videos/sort:alphabetic).

You can also refer:

1. https://www.hotwaxsystems.com/ofbiz-tutorials/
2. [Apache OFBiz Framework Tutorial - Developing Enterprise Application](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU-bf4QmR3zTxcjSiGtNOk09ngioyT4W) playlist on Youtube Channel [HotWaxU](https://www.youtube.com/user/HotWaxU)
3. Apache OFBiz Cookbook by Ruth Hoffman
4. Apache OFBiz Development: The Beginner's Tutorial by Jonathon Wong, Rupert Howell

Though the books explain about older version still you can get an idea about the basic architecture there.

If you are still in doubt you can subscribe to official mailing lists [here](http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html) and ask questions to the community.